# Battery Problem: Win7 always shows am on AC power, even when on battery power, any help?

Tags: battery

I am using a HP Probook 4510s and the battery started having problem, Windows 7 showed an alert advising to replace the battery. I bought a new battery which is working well but the battery indicator never changes from when I am on battery or on AC power. I have googled about it and I got a suggestion made top someone else:

> I suggest you to follows below steps: First open the Device Manager
>   and then you will need to expand Batteries. Then next step is to click
>   over Uninstall Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery which
>   by doing right click over it Finally steps is to restart your system.

It didnt work for me as the battery meter disappeared. I have also tried disabling other devices found under the battery list of the Device manager, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the HP Drivers/Support website.  They may have drivers needed for the battery to display properly.  From a quick glance, I don't see anything battery specific, but there are Essential System Updates and the HP Advisor utility, both of which many contain updates for your battery.  I use an HP as well and many times the Advisor has driver updates that aren't listed on the main site.